# URL redirection in php for Opera Mini browser

Tags: javascript, php, url, redirect, opera-mini

I would like to redirect all URLs opened from Opera Mini browser to specific browser using PHP. I have this code below but it is not working. Please help me.

```
if(! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('@(Opera Mini)@', $useragent)){

        $host = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if($host !== 'mywebsite.com/browser-error'){
            header('Location: ./browser-error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `$host` ? How do you get this `var`?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code. Is the edited one correct?
I tried to add current URL check because this code will be in every page even in /browser-error so I need to skip redirection if it is already in that page.

Answer (score 2):

According to [dev.opera.com](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-request-headers/), `opera mini` user-agent has the following format:

> User-Agent: Opera/9.80 ($PLATFORM_NAME$;
>   $PRODUCT_NAME$/$CLIENT_VERSION$/ $SERVER_VERSION$;U; $LOCALE$)
>   $PRESTO_VERSION$ $EQUIV_DESKTOP_VERSION$

Example:

```
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/8.0.1807/36.1609; U; en) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16
```

To detect it use:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false) {
    echo 'is opera mini';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PHP code to check the browser

```
<?
if(preg_match('/android.+opera m(ob|in)i/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
header('Location: http://');
```

Or try to use this PHP library

http://mobiledetect.net/